# Webstorm 11 EAP #WS-142.4148 and dart .packages

Tags: dart, webstorm

In the previous WebStorm 11 EAP build, performing a `pub upgrade` or `pub get` generated the dart `.packages` file instead of the `packages` directory used prior to Dart 1.12.

However in the current WebStorm EAP both the `.packages` file and the `packages` directory are generated. I would like to use only the `.packages` file.

Is there a setting in WebStorm that I can use to force the `.packages` and remove the `packages` symlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was changed so the `packages` directory is created again because several tools don't work (yet) without the `packages` directory (for example `pub run test`). 
There is no way to configure this in WebStorm currently. What you can do is to run `pub get`/`pub upgrade` from the command line with the `--no-package-symlinks` option.

See also:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/WEB-18006
- https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/327

Comment: Thanks for the info Gunter.